# Having trouble with javascript Replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

This code will replace the comma's no problem, but will leave the `$` for some reason... Is it set up wrong? Trying to replace the `$` also.

```
function doValidate() { 
    var valid = true;  
    document.likeItemSearchForm.sup.value = document.likeItemSearchForm.sup.value.replace(/\$|,/g, "")  
    return valid;   
}
```

Comment: `"$,,$,$".replace(/\$|,/g, "") === ""` for me.

Comment: what is going on with mine????? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`'asd$asd,asd,asd$,asd'.replace(/[\$,]/g,'');`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fTMZx/)
-edit- fixed link

Comment: You don't need ``\`` inside a character class.

Comment: Thanks, didn't check the link (woops)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
"$12,121.30".replace(/[\$,]/g, "");
```